# Terminate all processes when condition is met

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, starmap

I am using starmap to run testing function. 
Whats the best/safest way to terminate all processes when a process first finds the permutation [5,2,4,3,1]?

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time

def testing(lts):
    # code ....
    start_time = time.time()
    for x in range(1,500000):
        gg = [1,2,3,4,5]
        random.shuffle(gg)
        ### if gg==[5,2,4,3,1] terminate all processes
    total_time = time.time() - start_time
    return total_time

if __name__ == '__main__':

    with mp.Pool(processes=4) as pool:
    ret = pool.starmap(testing, [(lst,) for x in range(4)])
```

Comment: use a managed variable that you can set / test and quit the loops.

Comment: I did try to set a global var and set it to true and then inside function I use if _FINISH: break but no joy ...It doesn't stop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with all this `multiprocessing` stuff, but setting a global variable only works with threads. `multiprocessing` creates different processes, so the global variable will be duplicated and a change of value is only visible in the *current* process.

Instead, use a `Manager`, which creates a shared object between processes (dictionary, list for instance).

There may be simpler ways, but I chose to create a shared `Manager.list()` object, which is initially empty.

When the combination is found, just append something to the list. Test the list for emptyness in all processes. I've adapted your example so it works as-is (no need for `numpy` here, `random.shuffle` works fine.

```
import multiprocessing as mp, random
import time

def testing(lst):
    # code ....

    start_time = time.time()
    for x in range(1,500000):
        gg = [1,2,3,4,5]
        random.shuffle(gg)

        if gg==[5,2,4,3,1]:
            print(gg)
            lst.append(1)  # reflected on all processes
        if lst:
            # list is no longer empty: stop
            print("stop")
            break

    total_time = time.time() - start_time
    return total_time

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager = mp.Manager()
    lst = manager.list()

    with mp.Pool(processes=4) as pool:
       ret = pool.starmap(testing, [(lst,) for x in range(4)])

    print(ret)
```

a trace of execution:

```
[5, 2, 4, 3, 1]
stop
stop
stop
stop
[0.031249523162841797, 0.015624523162841797, 0.015624523162841797, 0.015624523162841797]
```

as we see, the 4 processes have stopped, when one found the "solution".