# Stop multiprocess pool when a condition is met and continue with program

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I've been trying to wrap my head around `multiprocessing` using an old python bitcoin mining program. Although relatively useless for mining, I figured this would be a great way to explore `multiprocessing`. However, I've hit a wall when it comes to stopping the processes when one of them achieves the goal they are all working towards.

I want to kill all multiprocessing pools when one of them finds the solution. Then allow the program to continue. I have tried `terminate()` and `join()`. I've attempted to include an `Event()`. I've tried using `Process` instead of `Pool` with the direction of a similar issue here: [Killing a multiprocessing process when condition is met](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54224989/killing-a-multiprocessing-process-when-condition-is-met). However, same problem. How can I stop all processes after a condition is met without exiting the program with something like `sys.exit()` that would kill the entire program?

I tried also `apply_sync` with the direction from this post: [Python Multiprocess Pool. How to exit the script when one of the worker process determines no more work needs to be done?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33447055/python-multiprocess-pool-how-to-exit-the-script-when-one-of-the-worker-process) However, it did not solve the problem of needing to continue executing the final functions of the program. In fact, it actually slowed the program significantly.

For clarity, I've included the code I tried based on the above mentioned link here:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from hashlib import sha256
import time





def SHA256(text):
    return sha256(text.encode("ascii")).hexdigest()

def solution_helper(args):
    solution, nonce = do_job(args)
    if solution:
        print(f"\nNonce Found: {nonce}\n")
        return True
    else:
        return False


class Mining():
    def __init__(self, workers, initargs):
        self.pool = Pool(processes=workers, initargs=initargs)

    def callback(self, result):
        if result:
            print('Solution Found...Terminating Processes...')
            self.pool.terminate()

    def do_job(self):
        for args in values:
            start_nonce = args[0]
            end_nonce = args[1]
            prefix_str = '0'*difficulty
            self.pool.apply_async(solution_helper, args=args, callback=self.callback)
            start = time.time()
            for nonce in range(start_nonce, end_nonce):
                text = str(block_number) + transactions + previous_hash + str(nonce)
                new_hash = SHA256(text)
                if new_hash.startswith(prefix_str):
                    print(f"Hashing: {text}")
                    print(f"\nSuccessfully mined bitcoin with nonce value: {nonce}\n")
                    print(f"New hash: {new_hash}")
                    total_time = str((time.time()-start))
                    print(f"\nEnd mning... Mining took {total_time} seconds\n")
                    return new_hash, nonce

        self.pool.close()
        self.pool.join()
        print('.Goodbye.')


block_number = 5
transactions = """
        bill->steve->20,
        jan->phillis->45
        """
previous_hash = '0000000b7c7723e4d3a8654c975fe4dd23d4d37f22d0ea7e5abde2225d1567dc6'
values = [(20000, 100000), (100000, 1000000), (1000000, 10000000), (10000000, 100000000)]
difficulty = 4
m = Mining(5, values)
m.do_job()
```

Here's the basic concept. It works great to start the processes, but I cannot figure out how to stop them:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from hashlib import sha256
import functools


MAX_NONCE = 1000000000

def SHA256(text):
    return sha256(text.encode("ascii")).hexdigest()

def nonce(block_number, transactions, previous_hash, prefix_str):
    import time
    start = time.time()
    for nonce in range(MAX_NONCE):
        text = str(block_number) + transactions + previous_hash + str(nonce)
        new_hash = SHA256(text)
        if new_hash.startswith(prefix_str):
            print(f"\nYay! Successfully mined bitcoins with nonce value:{nonce}")
            total_time = str((time.time()-start))
            print(f"\nend mining. Mining took: {total_time} seconds\n")
            print(new_hash + "\n")

def mine(block_number, transactions, previous_hash, prefix_zeros):
    from multiprocessing import Pool
    with Pool(4) as p:
        prefix_str = '0'*prefix_zeros
        p.map(nonce(block_number, transactions, previous_hash, prefix_str), [20000, 40000, 60000, 80000, 100000])


if __name__=='__main__':
    transactions="""
        bill->steve->20,
        jan->phillis->45
        """
    difficulty=7
    print("\nstart mining\n")
    new_hash = mine(5, transactions, '0000000b7c7723e4d3a8654c975fe4dd23d4d37f22d0ea7e5abde2225d1567dc6', difficulty)
    # Do some other things... Here is where I'd like to get to after the multiproccesses are killed
    print(f"\nMission Complete...{new_hash}\n") <---This never gets a chance to happen
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Multiprocess Pool. How to exit the script when one of the worker process determines no more work needs to be done?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33447055/python-multiprocess-pool-how-to-exit-the-script-when-one-of-the-worker-process)

Comment: @noxdafox I believe it may. I'm going to make a few changes based on that post and see what happens. It appears on the surface `apply_async` with a `callback` function may solve the issue. Thanks, I'll let you know if it does the job.

Comment: @noxdafox I'm not super familiar with OOP. Why are you passing `init` in `w=Workers(num_proc, init, [total_count]`?

Comment: @noxdafox It does seem to exit the process, but also exits the entire program. That solution doesn't actually solve my problem. I need to allow the rest of the program to run. It also magnified the amount of time it took to find a solution almost x5. So, I'm not sure if that is the best way to go. Thank you for the direction though.

Comment: You call to `p.map` is totally wrong. The first argument to `map` will be the *return value* from your call to `nonce`, which will be `None`. So you will call `nonce` once and then you will get an exception: `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable`. The second argument, `[20000, 40000, 60000, 80000, 100000]`, is not referenced anywhere by function `nonce`. You only get to pass to `map` the name of the function. If your function takes fixed arguments, then you need to use `functools.partial`.

Comment: Change `nonce` to return `True` on success and `False` on failure. Instead of using `p.map`, make multiple calls to `p.apply_asyc` and build a list of `AsyncResult` instances. Then periodically loop through them calling `ready()` to see if a result has come back. If `ready` returns `True` then call `get()` on the instance and if the result is `True` you are done. When you get out of the `with` block, `p.terminate()` will be called for you, killing all processes in the pool. You could also instead use a callback with `apply_async` and an event.